# What does hits in solr logs indicate?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, sunspot-solr, solr7

I see below log message in my solr logs

```html
webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} hits=1421599 status=0 QTime=26

o.a.s.c.ShardLeaderElectionContextBase make sure parent is created 
o.a.s.c.ZkController Core needs to recover:
```

what does hits in this log indicate ?, after this log , I see the cluster went down and failed leader election process. trying to understand is it high volume of reads and writes that took down the cluster ?

Comment: The ping request just confirms that the core is available and responding. The `hits` is the total number of documents in the core, and the `QTime` is low - meaning that this probably didn't put any pressure on any nodes at all. Does this happen every time you issue a ping request? I might suspect that this is a red herring and that the error lies somewhere else (have you confirmed that your JVM isn't running out of memory?) Which version of Solr?

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh , I am running solr 7.7, this issue is occurring intermittently, solr nodes keep running as usual and all of a sudden I see huge cpu spikes and nodes unable to choose leader and eventually cluster goes down. I tried getting logs around the time I observed CPU spike and only these ping logs and couple of read and update queries were seen at that time. Also my solr-promotheus-exporter is a older version it's failing to parse metrics values and keeps throwing error. so can that have any impact ?

Comment: Huge CPU spikes can be corelated to garbage collection or something similar; have you tried enabling verbose GC logging for your Solr nodes to see if something happens around that time? Since the entry gets logged, I would guess that it isn't the cause - since logging has to happen after everything else has been processed. Upgrading Solr might be something you'd want to look into; I wouldn't think that the exported could be the cause (as I'm guessing it only reads from the Solr API and doesn't integrate deeply into Solr?)

Comment: @MatsLindh I a using 9GB for solr heap. from the docs it's recommended number is 2Gb can this have any impact on CPU hikes, also if I don't provide any JVM OPTS for JVM memory, but the VM has 16 GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `hits` in the Solr logs is the same value of `numFound` returned by a Solr query. In other words, `hits` represents the number of documents that matches the query.

In your case the `hits` logged in response of the handler `/admin/ping` represents the number of documents in the Solr core/replica.